# How to separate a character column which contains both a double and an integer?

Tags: r

I have a character column which contains either of the following:

- Doubles and integers with commas, separated by a variable number of spaces (e.g. "3.40   128,489")
- Negative doubles which are represented by a double in  and integers with commas, separated by a variable number of spaces (e.g. "<1.20>  128,489")
- Only integers with commas (124,893)

I need two columns. One that has the double, and the other that has the integer. If the field only has the integer, the double column can be NA.

```
a <- c("2.45     238,948", "<1.40>  43,280", "1,234,580", "2.89 3389")
b <- data.frame(a)
```

I tried using the separate function:

```
c <- lapply(b, function(x) {x %>% separate(a[1], into = c("rate","Period_Plan"), sep =" ", fill = 'left' )})
```

However, I get this error:

> Error in UseMethod("separate") :
> no applicable method for 'separate' applied to an object of class "character"

Comment: There is no `c` in the example created.  Your data.frame object is `b`..  Based on your `b` data, `b %>% separate(a, into = c("rate", "Period_Plan"), sep = "\\s+", fill = "left") %>% mutate(across(everything(), ~ as.numeric(str_remove_all(.x, "[,<>]"))))` should work

Comment: @akrun This worked well, other than the last part where you remove the <>. Instead of removing the <>, it needs to remove it and turn the corresponding value into a negative. Can you advise?

Comment: My code removed `<>`.  If it should be changed, use `str_replace` instead of `str_remove`

Answer (score 1):

```
read.table(text=chartr("<>", "- ",sub("^(?=\\S+$)", "NA ", gsub(",","",a), perl = TRUE)))
     V1      V2
1  2.45  238948
2 -1.40   43280
3    NA 1234580
4  2.89    3389
```

Breaking this down:

```
d <- gsub(",","",a) # remove commas
e <- sub("^(?=\\S+$)", "NA ", d, perl = TRUE) # add NA if no double
f <- chartr("<>", "- ", e) #convert <> to negative
read.table(text = f)# read into table

     V1      V2
1  2.45  238948
2 -1.40   43280
3    NA 1234580
4  2.89    3389
```